# split view controller navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uisplitviewcontroller, nested

I know this is possible, but I'm just not finding the example to help me do it.  I have a split view controller that shows tree families for example.  The left master frame shows Hardwood, Evergreen, etc.  When I select Hardwood, the detail frame shows general information about Hardwoods, selecting Evergreen shows similar information about evergreens.  If I select the detail disclosure button accessory on the Evergreen, I want the master view to be replaced with a list of Evergreens, and selecting on a specific evergreen will give detailed information about that specific type of tree.  Navigating back from the evergreen tree family in the master view, should take me back to the tree family listing and clear the detail view so it's ready to display information about the family chosen in the family master view.
I have the family master view working fine.  It's how to setup the segue to the second level splitview that I'm having trouble with.  Any help or tutorials showing the nesting relationship would be appreciated.
Thanks

Updated, Here are mockups of pictures of what is happening.
[image: This is what I start with. The left view has a list of tree families, and the right has general information about that family. Ignore the electrical outlet, It's just a picture I had handy.]
This is what I start with.  The left view has a list of tree families, and the right has general information about that family.  Ignore the electrical outlet, It's just a picture I had handy.
[image: When I click on the accessory for the selected family, I get this screen, with individual tree types, and information about those tree types. The information and fields does not match with the information from the family detail view so I can't just reuse that.]
When I click on the accessory for the selected family, I get this screen, with individual tree types, and information about those tree types.  The information and fields does not match with the information from the family detail view so I can't just reuse that.

[image: When I click the Family navigation button (back button) at the top of the table view, it takes the table view back like it should, but the detail view is stuck and I can't get it to go back where it should be.]
When I click the Family navigation button (back button) at the top of the table view, it takes the table view back like it should, but the detail view is stuck and I can't get it to go back where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tutorial I found helpful was;
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial

Comment: That is a good tutorial, but I need to take it one step farther.  If I were to use the tutorial as an example, After selecting a Monster, I would want the master table view (left hand side) to change and give me a list of weapons I could equip that monster with.  That's where I'm getting mixed up.

Comment: The closest I have gotten is adding another tableview controller segued to by the accessory on the mastertableview.  Then when I select the tree in the second tableviewcontroller, it gives me the detail of the tree I want, but when I use the treeFamily button (basically the back button) on the tableviewcontroller to go back to the master table, it does not replace the detail view controller with the correct view controller no matter what tree family I select.

Comment: It may be better, to do things differently (apologies in advance if I have misunderstood). I would have the detail disclosure in the detail view, then push a new view controller into your detail view. For example, you tap evergreens in the master view, the detail view changes to show your general information about evergreens, you tap a detail disclosure in the detail view and you then push in another view (into the detail view) with your list of evergreens and so on. This will keep your navigation straightforward. Or keep your lists all in the master view with details in the detail view.

Comment: Sounds like you would have a second master detail screen inside the detail of your first splitview.  That would get pretty crowded.  And no apologies.  Maybe I do need to rethink my UI.

Comment: If you want to update your master view based on a selection in the detail view you could add an observer in your master view and trigger it from your detail view, for example;[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateMyTableView:) name:@"RefreshMasterNotification" object:nil]; in your master view and then [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshMasterNotification" object:self]; in your detail view.

Comment: It should work the other way around too.  The problem is my detail view doesn't know when to switch back to the detail view associated with the primary master view when the master view transitions back.  I just don't have the words to describe this right.

Comment: So, when the "Family" button in the (master) navigation bar is pressed, you want the detail view to transition back.  You should replace the back button with a custom `UIBarButtonItem`, and give it a target/action to a method which pops the master side navigation controller (to return to your hardwood/evergreen table), and removes the second detail screen, revealing the initial detail screen.  How you do this last part depends on how your app currently works (in particular how the second detail screen is presented), so you will need to post some code if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, for now, I'm going away from the split view controller to get the rest of the screen display logic down.  For now, it's back to simple table views calling table views.  Thanks for all of you help.